# I'm trying to store an xml string in a php variable and print it as is

Tags: php, xml, variables

I'm trying to run the code below and print the xml as is. However, when I run it , the output is 'Happy 20'. I've tried using nowdoc and heredoc, but still get the same output. Can someone please enlighten me as to what's going on and how to print the string as is. Thanks much.

```
<?php

$temp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <resultset>
               <row>
                <name>Happy</name>
                <age>20</age>
               </row>
              </resultset>';       
   echo $temp;
?>
```

Comment: if you want to see it (the tags), in a browser.  You have three options basically,  `header('Content-type: text/xml')`, `htmlspecialchars` or put it in a `textarea`.  I would go with the first one.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why that's happening and don't really want to print it in a browser.

Comment: If you're not using a browser, you must be running it from the command line. Then you should see the XML.

Comment: In the browser use `View Source`, you'll see the XML. The browser is treating the XML tags as HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what I would do is set the content type, by default its HTML

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$temp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <resultset>
           <row>
            <name>Happy</name>
            <age>20</age>
           </row>
          </resultset>';       
echo $temp;
```

You also don't need this thing `?>`. It's actually a bad idea to have ending tags as it can put any whitespace onto the end of your XML (file download, or whatever).

Also with `header` you cannot send the header, if you have output anything.  That includes space before the `<?php` tag.

Whenever a server returns anything it's just text.  Even images are basically just text.  The thing that makes them special is the type of content the browser sees them as. You can set this as shown above.

As @Barmar said in the comments, if your outputting XML it should be the only thing you output.  It's not as forgiving as HTML is.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, that gives me:                                                                                                     
 XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </meta>.
Location: http://localhost:8000/
Line Number 11, Column 7:    </head>
------^

Comment: @user1754784 There's no `<meta`> or `</head>` in the script you show above. Are you printing those things elsewhere in the script? If you want to send XML, you shouldn't send anything else.

Comment: Even if you don't have those in this particular file, you may be including some other file(s) that outputs that stuff.  It's very important to only have XML if you are returning it for the response.  Otherwise, whatever is trying to read that response will not be able to.